# How to make directory writable?

Tags: permissions, raspbian, wordpress

I just installed apache2 and WordPress on my RPi. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/web-server-wordpress/worksheet.md).

After its successful installation, I moved on to customization. But when I upload any images, etc.

I receive the following message,

> Error rit Logo ful…2 - Copy.jpg
>   Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/01.
>   Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I am unsure of how to proceed. Do I have to change the file permissions to writable or change owner of the directory ?

Please advise on how to overcome this error along with appropriate commands.

Comment: The web-server's group should be used for the web-related files, and also, the server usually owns the files too. If only the group is set, then you should make the directories (and files you want the server to change) group-writable (`chmod g+w`). If the server actually owns the files, it should work without setting permissions.

Comment: I am sure who owns the files. The directory is /var/www/ and the server is apache2. I tried to upload a image file using wordpress' customization tool. That is where I received the said error message.

Comment: Just check `ls -l` on the files (and `ls -ld` on the directory you want to be writable) and tell me what you see.

Comment: @orion I got the following                                        pi@pi01 /var/www/wp-content/themes $ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 18 18:18 .

Comment: Is `www-data` the username that apache uses? Check `ps -up $(pidof httpd)` and the apache config file for `User` and `Group` keywords. Also check if `[...]/uploads/2015/...` has the same users and permissions as the rest of the directories.

Comment: @ORION found the solution. Posting it as answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that seems to be working was

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

Credits to Raspberry user [nevil-verdoold](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/26396/nevil-verdoold) and also to [orion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/61909/orion).